# Why img is not loading even path is correct? Laravel 9 latest version

Tags: php

I am trying to show img in nav bar of my project, in laravel 9 latest version. Syntax is correct, path is correct, even when i try to show img on anywhere on page just like normal img it was not loading anywhere even code in correct need help guys.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
            TMHS
            <img src="resources/images/logo/tmhslogo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            TMHS logo</a>
```

Comment: If you try to open image in new tab (right click > open image), is your URL correct? Maybe try to add `/` before your image url.

Comment: Anything you want to be viewed _publicly_ goes into the `public` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the image to your [public](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/structure#the-public-directory) directory, the resources directory isn't publically accessable by default.